# Use of multiplying and dividing same number in code

Tags: c, matlab, embedded

I have observed this below line code in MATLAB generated C file.

```
Variable_x= (T_S16) ((((T_S32) varibale_y) * 13107) >> 13);
```

If 13107 shift to left side 13 times, then it becomes 1.

What's the use of multiplying 13107 and dividing same no?

Comment: But its not 13107 what is shifted, is `varibale_y*13107`.

Comment: Overall it performing integer calculations for multiplying the variable by `1.6`.

Comment: looks like a [bit-twiddling hack](http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) or *something of the kind*.

Answer (score 3):

It is not "multiplying and dividing same number".
It is multiplying a number by 13107 and dividing that product by 8192 - a ratio of 1.5999755859375.

As suggested by [@ Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61662886/use-of-multiplying-and-dividing-same-number-in-code#comment109073291_61662886), this is certainly scaling an integer by about 1.6 using integer math.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can I use a different combination of numbers like 8 and 5 to get 1.6?

Comment: @RajuDasar Yes, code could use `x*8/5`, but the that might use a _slow_ division vs. the original code's shift.  Speed vs. accuracy.